# You can't specify target tablet xxxxx for update in FROM clause, al intentar hacer un insert en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Vengo de trabajar con SQL Server y ahora que estoy en MySQL estoy teniendo problemas básicos para hacer un `INSERT`.
Lo que yo quiero es hacer un insert con el resultado de una consulta pero no soy capaz. Tengo una tabla llamada *piso* que tiene como clave primaria un código numérico autoincremental ordenado de menor a mayor (1,2,3,4...). La sintaxis que me da error es:

```
INSERT INTO PISO (codigo)
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(codigo)+1 FROM PISO));
```

El error que me sale es:

> You can't specify target tablet 'PISOS' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No te deja, porque estás intentando insertar en la misma tabla de donde estás haciendo el select.

Pero si tu campo **codigo** está definido como clave primaria y como autoincremental, entonces no necesitas calcular tú cuál es el próximo valor, deja que el motor de base de datos lo haga por ti ¿no? Para eso le has puesto AUTO_INCREMENT al campo.

Simplemente diciéndole NULL como valor para el campo autoincremental, el motor se encargará de darle el siguiente valor:

INSERT INTO PISO (codigo) VALUES (NULL);

También, si haces el insert para dar valor a otros campos, no necesitas indicar el valor para código:

INSERT INTO PISO (otrocampo1, otrocampo2) VALUES ('valor1', 'valor2');

Siendo **codigo** autoincremental, se le da valor automáticamente.

Comment: Si puedes insertar y hacer un select, hay que hacer un alias a la tabla del select.